# When you should split the protocol handling code into Deferreds in Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

Implementing a client protocol in Twisted, my current code does a lot of work on each protocol unit recieved, it doesn't use I/O so no Deferreds are currently used.
The processing is not meant to be intensive but it open to pluggable interfaces.

Is there a treshold to do this partition?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider "deferring" at points where plugins are going to be called, since you can't predict whether they will do any I/O to databases, remote processes, web services, whatever.

Look into using [`@inlineCallbacks`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.1.0/api/twisted.internet.defer.html#inlineCallbacks), which will simplify your life in terms of breaking up your processing into Deferreds simply by using Python's `yield` statement. Then you can experiment with breaking up your compute-intensive work in various ways, perhaps to give other protocol handlers a chance to run and complete, especially if some handlers are compute-intensive and others are not.

Comment: I am considering splitting at the plugin calls but i want to know where is the limit or a recommended way of doing the split.

Comment: If you convert your code to using @inlineCallbacks decorator, then you can convert your plugin calls that might be something like `results = plugin.method(arg1,arg2)` to `results = yield plugin.method(arg1,arg2)` and this will effectively split your processing at the plugin call. This is the 'inline' aspect of inlineCallbacks, and it really helps neaten up your Twisted code.

Comment: This answer isn't really correct.  If you break up a function with `yield` statements, it won't necessarily become asynchronous unless the thing being yielded is a `Deferred`; and even then, that `Deferred` must be *unfired* at the time it is yielded; you'd have to `yield deferLater(...)` in order to have any effect.  Better for this purpose is `twisted.internet.task.cooperate`.

Comment: Yeeps! I defer to @Glyph (pun not intended, and probably has been heard a hundred times before, but it just popped in my head).

Comment: @Glyph - thanks also for the edit, could have sworn I checked the spelling, which I *did* get right in my comment, must have copy/pasted from an early comment draft. (I enjoyed your Boston Meetup talk, couldn't see the slides tho.)

Comment: But the question remains, is it even necessary?